# How to call a exe in multi-thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, exe

I need to call an exe from my c++ application. The exe takes "10 secs" to complete the process. I need to call the "exe" multiple times. So I plan to call the "exe" multiple times from my C++ application using Multi-thread. Can some one provide a sample to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't make assumptions on "how long" a program runs...

Comment: What part of this are you struggling with?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan to call the exe in multithread.

Comment: It's still not clear. Starting another process is the same no matter how many threads are involved. Do you know how to create and manage threads? Is that your problem? Or do you know that, but don't know how to start processes? You need to make the question clear. You need to expand and tells us more. Tell us what you know, what you've tried, what you don't know, and where you are stuck. Or would you prefer for us just to deliver you the code that you need?

Comment: -1 for "can someone provide a sample?" rather than asking a question about a specific part of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you waitable process handle.

It is in [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data structure filled by `CreateProcess`.

If you need portable solution then use [`Boost.Interprocess`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). With it you can share data between threads in different processes. `Boost.Interprocess` does not contain ways to start a process; that can be achieved in semi-portable manner with C functions like `system()`. Note that the thread calling `system()` for starting other process is blocked until the other process exits.

Comment: Windows is not the only operating system, to paraphrase Jeanette Winterson

Comment: Do any other commonly used OS-s use .exe?

Comment: @jt234 A clean C++ solution is usually to be preferred over a platform specific solution.

Comment: @David Understandable. Perhaps this question should elaborate the operating system.

Comment: @jt234 Yes - depending on your definition of 'commonly-used', DOS, OpenVMS, Symbian and OS/2 (ok, maybe OS/2 is a little niche now...)

Comment: @jt234 The shop I work in writes everything first on Windows and then ports to Linux.  We have a tendency to (incorrectly) use the term "exe" (no ".") as short-hand to refer to Linux executables.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this MSDN example to run an "exe".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Link only answers are not great. Can you do better?